# How to increment cglm vec3s?

Tags: c, glm-math

I'm following [this C++ tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Camera) for learning OpenGL, but am using C myself. Because of this, I have to use the [cglm](https://github.com/recp/cglm) library instead of the standard [glm](https://github.com/g-truc/glm) library for C++. The OpenGL tutorial shows adding vector3s and floats like this:

```cpp
glm::vec3 cameraPos   = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f,  3.0f);
glm::vec3 cameraFront = glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);

//...

const float cameraSpeed = 0.05f;

cameraPos += cameraSpeed * cameraFront;
```

I can't do the same in my C code, since I get errors such as `expression must have arithmetic type` or `expression must be a modifiable lvalue`. This was my attempt at fixing it:

```c
vec3 cameraPos = {0.0f, 0.0f, 3.0f};
vec3 cameraFront = {0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f};

//...

const float cameraSpeed = 0.05f;

vec3 b;
glm_vec3_mul((vec3) {cameraSpeed}, cameraFront, b);

glm_vec3_add(cameraPos, b, cameraPos);
```

However, this does not solve the issue, and I think this is because the `glm_vec3_add()` function is not incrementing. Is there some sort of cglm function that can increment these values?

Comment: `glm_vec3_add(cameraPos, b, cameraPos)` calcualtes the sum of  `cameraPos` and `b` and writes the result to `cameraPos`. See the implementation https://github.com/recp/cglm/blob/master/include/cglm/vec3.h (line 271)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not [`glm_vec3_add`](https://cglm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vec3.html#c.glm_vec3_add), but [`glm_vec3_mul`](https://cglm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vec3.html#c.glm_vec3_mul). `glm_vec3_mul` multiplies two vectors, but you want to multiply a vector by a scalar. For this you need to use [`glm_vec3_scale`](https://cglm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/vec3.html#c.glm_vec3_scale):

<s>`glm_vec3_mul((vec3) {cameraSpeed}, cameraFront, b);`</s>

```c
glm_vec3_scale(cameraFront, cameraSpeed, b);
```